# Sql query to retrieve data in described format

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

Struggling to conceptualize this query. Any help will be appreciated.

Dataset

Table: Audit

```
Date   |Action  |PackageId
1/1/15 |Active  |1
1/2/15 |DeActive|1
11/3/16|Update  |2
12/3/16|Update  |2
13/3/16|Update  |2
14/3/16|Update  |2
```

Table: Package

```
Id|Name
1 |package1
2 |package2
```

Table: Item

```
Id|ItemName|PackageId
1 | item1  |1
2 | item2  |1
3 | item3  |1
4 | item4  |2
5 | item5  |2
```

The relationship between these tables is `Audit.PackageID Is foreign key to Package.Id and Item.PackageId is foreign key to Pacakge.id`

For the above data, I want to generate a report like this

```
Package.Name|Item.ItemName|Audit.Date|Audit.Action
package1    |  item1      | 1/1/15   | Active
package1    |  item2      | 1/2/15   | DeActive
package1    |  item3      | NULL     | NULL
package2    |  item4      | 11/3/16  | update
package2    |  item5      | 12/3/16  | update
package2    |  NULL       | 13/3/16  | update
package2    |  NULL       | 14/3/16  | update
```

basically the item or audit information is not duplicated and package information is duplicated if item/audit information is more than number of packages. Hope it makes sense.

I basically need to write a stored procedure that will return a dataset as described above. This result is then fed into a report parser that will replace all `NULL` with `blanks` and generate an Excel report.
The database is `SQL-Server-2000`.

Comment: Based on your sample data, how do you obtain `12/3/16` on the final report...also can you build a sample on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @Hackerman: Corrected the data to include `12/3/16 in audit`. Will create sample on fiddle and post the link

Comment: Thanks @Mukul, with the sample data I am going to get the right query in no time!

Comment: @Hackerman: Dont really know whats wrong but the fiddle is giving `create script error` on each script I write. I even tried its text to ddl thing, resolves to correct ddl and fails

Comment: First you need to create the table, and below the create instructions, you need to add your insert statements, the you need to click on "build schemas"...also make sure that you select the right database engine(Dropdown on the right side of the Sql Fiddle Logo).

Comment: @I am trying that, seems to be creating tables fine for MySQL database selection but not for SQL server 2008/2014. would it be much difference for you to build the query on MySQL ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115457/discussion-between-mukul-goel-and-hackerman).

Comment: Create it in MySQL, no problem

Comment: @Hackerman: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb446 Give this a try would you? not sure if this is exactly correct. could not set up Foreign key constraints. But it does have the data, should help though

Comment: I am fine with the tables and data, it should work :)

Comment: @Hackerman: perfect: Thanks for the help. cheers(y)

Comment: At first glance, you should aim to use a view for this, not a stored procedure.

Comment: @PeterM.: Thanks for the input. Though I believe, If I can write a query to populate a view with this data, then I can write that query enclosed in a stored procedure. Why do you think a view would be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you are trying to do is fit two reports into one table; you have the Package Items report and the Package Audit Report.  Typically you do this at the reporting layer with sub-reports.

If you have to do it this way, you'll have to generate the two reports into tables with keys so that they can be joined together.  Since you are using SQL 2000, you don't have the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to generate some sequence numbers... which is unfortunate.  So instead you can create temporary tables with incrementing identity fields.

Here's the schema you provided:

```
CREATE TABLE #Audit
    (Date varchar(7), Action varchar(8), PackageId int)
;

INSERT INTO #Audit
    (Date, Action, PackageId)
VALUES
    ('1/1/15', 'Active', 1),
    ('1/2/15', 'DeActive', 1),
    ('11/3/16', 'Update', 2),
    ('12/3/16', 'Update', 2),
    ('13/3/16', 'Update', 2),
    ('14/3/16', 'Update', 2)
;

CREATE TABLE #Package
    (Id int, Name varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO #Package
    (Id, Name)
VALUES
    (1, 'package1'),
    (2, 'package2')
;

CREATE TABLE #Item
    (Id int, ItemName varchar(5), PackageId int)
;

INSERT INTO #Item
    (Id, ItemName, PackageId)
VALUES
    (1, 'item1', 1),
    (2, 'item2', 1),
    (3, 'item3', 1),
    (4, 'item4', 2),
    (5, 'item5', 2)
;
```

Then you create two more tables to hold your two separate reports and populate them.  The report tables need an identity field so that it generates a unique number for each row in the report:

```
create table #PackageItemsReport 
(   PackageItemsId int identity(1,1), 
    PackageId int, 
    PackageName varchar(8), 
    ItemName varchar(5)
)

insert into #PackageItemsReport
(PackageId,PackageName,ItemName)
select #Package.Id, #package.Name, #item.ItemName 
from #Package
join #Item
on #Package.Id = #item.PackageId
order by #Package.Id, #item.ItemName 

create table #PackageAuditReport 
(   PackageAuditId int identity(1,1), 
    PackageID int, 
    PackageName varchar(8), 
    AuditDate varchar(7), 
    AuditAction varchar(8)
)

insert into #PackageAuditReport
(PackageID,PackageName,AuditDate,AuditAction)
select #Package.Id, #Package.Name, #Audit.Date, #Audit.Action 
from #Package
join #Audit
on #Audit.PackageId = #Package.Id
order by #Package.Id, #Audit.Date, #Audit.Action
```

Then you need to join the two reports together using the package ID and the row numbers generated:

```
select ISNULL(PackageItemsReport.PackageName, PackageAuditReport.PackageName) Name,
    ItemName,
    AuditDate,
    AuditAction
from
(
    select #PackageItemsReport.*, PackageItemsId - MinPackageItemsId RowNum
    from #PackageItemsReport
    join
    (
    select PackageID, MIN(PackageItemsId) MinPackageItemsId
    From #PackageItemsReport
    group by PackageID
    ) MinPackageItemsIds
    on #PackageItemsReport.PackageID = MinPackageItemsIds.PackageID
) PackageItemsReport
full join
(
    select #PackageAuditReport.*, PackageAuditId - MinPackageAuditId RowNum
    from #PackageAuditReport
    join
    (
    select PackageID, MIN(PackageAuditId) MinPackageAuditId
    From #PackageAuditReport
    group by PackageID
    ) MinPackageAuditIds
    on #PackageAuditReport.PackageID = MinPackageAuditIds.PackageID
) PackageAuditReport
on PackageItemsReport.PackageID = PackageAuditReport.PackageID
    and PackageItemsReport.RowNum = PackageAuditReport.RowNum
order by ISNULL(PackageItemsReport.PackageID, PackageAuditReport.PackageID),
    ISNULL(PackageItemsReport.RowNum, PackageAuditReport.RowNum)
```

It's messy... thank goodness the ROW_NUMBER() function was added after SQL Server 2000.  It's much easier now.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I tried the this out with test data and works perfect. Will give this a try with actual table and dataset tomorrow. Should be fine though.